# "The LAN connection to apache2 with another device is not working."

Tags: apache2, networkmanager, hostapd, nmcli

I am using MiniOS Standard.

I created an access point with NetworkManager that assigned the address 10.42.0.1 to my machine.
Then, I set up a local server using apache2 and followed these steps:

1- Created an HTML file at /var/www/site.com/site.html with a simple HTML script.
2- Created the file etc/apache2/sites-available/site.conf and added the following content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
Servername site.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/site.com
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

3- Restarted apache2
4- Added the information “127.0.0.1   site.com” to /etc/hosts.

Then, I opened the browser, and indeed, the site opened!

However, I encountered a problem: When connecting my phone to the created access point, I can only open the page /var/www/html/index.html, which is already created by default in apache and only works when I enter the IP address 10.42.0.1 exclusively.

Será que existe alguma coisa que eu devo activar para permitir que os clientes usem o apache2?